# Web served image in PDF?

Tags: pdf

Does PDF and/or Adobe Reader support including an image by URL so that you can insert a dynamic images from a web server into a document?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is both yes and no.  If you look in the [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (I'm going by version 1.7) in section 7.11.5, you'll see that a stream within a PDF document can be represented by an URL.  So yes, you can go ahead and specify that a PDF has, say, its image content in the specified URL.

The problem will be that when you specify an image within PDF, you are specifying a PARTICULAR image that must have a particular data length and encoding.  Simply specifying dimensions, dct compression (aka jpg), and URL is not enough.  Images are contained in streams of a particular length.  If the stream is too long or too short, it is considered an error.

So you can have images dynamically served up, provided that they are always exactly the same byte length.  I think.  And I say this because the specification is somewhat ambiguous as to what happens when you set the length to 0 in the stream dictionary.

Now, is doing this practical?  Maybe - you'll need a fairly strong PDF toolkit in order to be able to author these documents.  And if you have that, I think you'd be better off authoring the entire PDF document that your clients want on the fly rather than trying to substitute an image at read time.

Comment: Per 7.3.8.2 Table 5, it seems pretty clear that /Length is the number of bytes within the PDF (to be ignored when referencing an external file), not the length of the external file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can place a dynamic image in a PDF document in this manner.  It's possible to dynamically create an entire PDF document using web-hosted content (using PHP, Coldfusion, etc.) but changing that content later on the web server will not dynamically update previously generated PDF documents, which is what it sounds like you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As PDFs are meant to be portable by nature (PORTABLE Document Format) and thus, not always viewed online, this goes against the very principle of the document format, and is not supported as far as I know.

You could include a reference to an image at the time of generation of the PDF, but said image will embedded into the PDF, not linked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pdf.js and modify the rendering methods slightly so that you inject your image. You can find pdf.js here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

You can also use FlexPaper which has an API that allows you to overlay your document with images
http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/